# HTML : how can I show format date " yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm "

Tags: jquery, html

how can I show format date " yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm " into input type "datettime-local" in the picture I missed "hh:mm"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbw4Q.png)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in JavaScript:

```
var da = new Date();
var year = da.getFullYear(),
    month = 1+da.getMonth(),
    day = da.getDate(),
    hours = da.getHours(),
    mins = da.getMinutes();
if (month<10)
    month = `0${month}`;
if (day<10)
    day = `0${day}`;
if (hours<10)
    hours = `0${hours}`;
if (mins<10)
    mins = `0${mins}`;
var d = year+'/'+month+'/'+day,
    t = hours+':'+mins,
    result = d+' '+t;
document.write(result);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) out for alternative ways to achieve this result. There exist several external plugins that make it easier to format dates in JavaScript and jQuery.